# How should I handle the 2 .pfx files on my desktop?

Tags: uwp

Earlier today I asked [How do I get the .pfx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58793944/how-do-i-get-the-pfx-file) Richard Zhang answered that question. I have a follow-up question. Right now the Package.appxmanifest file has a reference to the new .pfx file. Would it be best if I copied that .pfx file from off of my laptop onto my desktop? Or should I use the reference to the old .pfx file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test certificate file can be replaced. If you need the test certificate, the recommended practice is to use a different certificate on a different device. In other words, it is recommended that you regenerate the test certificate when you replace the device.

But this behavior is not friendly to developers who frequently change development equipment. You can consider removing the reference to the test certificate in the project file.

If your device is in developer mode, you will be allowed to install unsigned apps, so you don't need to worry about testing the certificate.

1. Unload the UWP Project

[image: 144f5585-9b2d-42a6-a1e7-b2169db54f0e.png]

2. Edit the `.csproj` file

[image: d8cd954c-2030-48e6-b909-0fca0a201aff.png]

3. Remove the related tags:

```xml
<!-- These tags need to be removed -->

<PackageCertificateThumbprint>F351F9FFDDB465E9457269B175C0A8432AD340F2</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
<PackageCertificateKeyFile />

...

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="TestApplication_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
</ItemGroup>
```

4. Reload project

---

This way you will find that there is no test certificate in the project file list (although it still exists in the project file directory), this does not affect your normal debugging, but it can help you solve the problem of repeatedly generating test certificates.

Best regards.